# Import specific SMS from default sms app to my applicaton

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor, sms

I want to know how I can import SMS from default SMS app to my application.
I have code for accessing the whole inbox but I just need to fetch sms at a time..
Please do answer.
Thanks in advance..!!

This is my list code to get all SMS

```
public void refreshSmsInbox() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    do {
        String str =  getContactName(this,smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress)) +
                "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
        arrayAdapter.add(str);
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}

public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
    arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is the code where I am trying to access SMS

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. How is the code you have not working? What exactly do you mean by "I just need to fetch sms at a time"?

Comment: I need to fetch sms by a specific number not whole inbox

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49835778).

Comment: let me check and then i will tell you.

Comment: thanks a lot it helps me a lot.